# Cleanup of iterators that have not been fully exhausted

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-3.5, paramiko

My main usage of generators is processing of rows of CSV files stored on a remote server. It allows me to have consistent interfaces of linearly processing the data stored in them.

Now, I am using paramiko in order to access an SFTP server that stores the files - and paramiko has an outstanding issue of not properly closing connections if you did not close the file itself.

I've got a simple interface of accessing a single file on the sftp (this is obviously a pseudocode - I am omitting the connection error handling code and so on).

```
 def sftp_read_file(filename):
       with paramiko.open(filename) as file_obj:
          for item in csv.reader(file_obj):
               yield item

 def csv_append_column(iter_obj, col_name, col_val):
     # header
     yield next(iter_obj) + (col_name, )
     for item in iter_obj:
         yield item + (col_val, )
```

Let's say I would like to test a set of transformations done to the file by running the script for a limited amount of rows:

```
def main():
    for i, item in enumerate(csv_append_column(sftp_read_file('sftp://...'), 'A', 'B')):
        print(item)
        if i > 0 and i % 100 == 0:
            break
```

The script will exit, but the interpreter will never terminate without SIGINT. What are my possible solutions?

Comment: do `from __future__ import generator_stop` might be propegation of StopIteration that's causing the issue see [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)... nevermind, I don't think I understand your issue.

Comment: Have you tried just calling sys.exit()?

Comment: @pvg Of course it works. Question isn't about 'how to make it work', but how to properly deallocate generators that are not used anymore, as they do not seem to be properly garbage-collected in my case.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Good catch. I don't think you do indeed, but the propagation of StopIteration is one of the issues I had to get over myself while debugging - thanks for the pointer.

Comment: if you keep a reference to the generator that needs to be closed it has a `.close()` method that closes the generator, whether it does the garbage collection or not it will exit the `with` block in the generator.

Comment: Why do you think it is the generator that is causing this and not `paramiko`, can you offer a more reproducible example?

Comment: Also, `Python 3.5` introduced PEP 479 so I'm not sure as to how that might be an issue.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have constructed an example that was supposed (not) to work. Then realised it worked flawlessly - as I have, to be honest expected myself. Turns out paramiko's file closure cleanup would sometimes hang for no reason, and it's an ongoing bug for a few years. So cleanup did happen - it just would never finish.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t the most elegant solution, but maybe we could build off @tadhg-mcdonald-jensen’s suggestion by wrapping the generator in an object:

```
class Stoppable(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.generator = fn

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.generator

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        self.generator.close()
```

And then use it like this:

```
def main():
    with Stoppable(sftp_read_file('sftp://...')) as reader:
        for i, item in enumerate(csv_append_column(reader, 'A', 'B')):
            print(item)
            if i > 0 and i % 100 == 0:
                break
```

---

Alternatively, we can just wrap the generator itself if we aren't using the generator methodology for streaming:

```
def stopit(fn):
    rg = [ x for x in fn ]
    for x in rg:
        yield x
```

Now we can call it like:

```
def main():
    for i, item in enumerate(csv_append_column(stopit(sftp_read_file('...')), 'A', 'B')):
        print(item)
        if i > 0 and i % 100 == 0:
            break
```

This will make sure the with block exits and `paramiko` closes the sftp connection but comes at the expense of reading all of the lines into memory at once.